# Dependency in requirement.txt not installed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, docker, flask, ffmpeg

I need to deploy a flask app to google app engine.
I used docker and there lines are in Dockerfile:

```
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
```

In requirements.txt file:

```
Flask==0.12
gunicorn==19.6.0
boto==2.46.1
gcs-oauth2-boto-plugin==1.8
ffmpeg-normalize
```

It is supposed to install install all dependencies. But somehow "ffmpeg-normalize" is not installed in google app engine instances.

Can anyone help me with that?

If there is another better way doing the package installation, I will be happy to go with as well. Thanks!!

Comment: Where are the logs from the build?

Comment: Collecting ffmpeg-normalize (from -r /app/requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading ffmpeg-normalize-0.4.3.tar.gz

Comment: Running setup.py bdist_wheel for ffmpeg-normalize: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for ffmpeg-normalize: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/02/84/99/95e5c41938f6d681c09f32550dae603514d2f325d0d40595b5

Comment: Looks like it installed.   Slip inside the container and poke around.   docker exec -it --rm <imagename> /bin/sh

Comment: Probably, version number is missing???

Comment: @EricZhang Even when I put version number there, it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be happening for a few reasons.  Here are my guesses :)

How do you know the package isn't being installed?  Can you share the docker build output that happens when you `gcloud app deploy`?

Another thing to try here, just to be sure is to run:

```
gcloud app instances list
```

Then...

```
gcloud beta app instances ssh [instance] 
    --service [svc] 
    --version [v] 
    --container gaeapp
```

From there, you can ls around in the container and see *exactly* what got installed.

I would guess that the pip package is getting installed, but maybe you just didn't install the native dependency you need for ffmpeg.  Here's an example of how to do this with Docker + App Engine:

https://github.com/JustinBeckwith/next17/blob/master/videobooth/Dockerfile

Since you're already using docker - what happens when you build this container locally?  Have you tried:

```
docker build -t myapp .
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 myapp
```

Hopefully one of this helps give you a clue to figuring out what's happening.  Hope this helps!